# Design problem with an an InterpolatingFunction-like object: bad performance over a remote kernel

Tags: design-patterns

I these last times, I found myself using often the following approach.

Given some data, I make some preliminary, common, computations and I store these results in an `Association` wrapped with some symbol, maybe together with the given data. I found `Association` more useful than `List` and `Sequence` to later access these intermediate results or data and to identify the preprocessed expression for pattern matching.

For example:

```
SVDAnalysis[matrix_?MatrixQ, vector_?VectorQ] :=
  Module[{svd},
     svd = SingularValueDecomposition[maxtrix];
     [...]
     SVDAnalysis[<| "SVDDecomposition" -> svd, "RightHandSide" -> vector, [...]  |>]
  ]
```

Generally I add some `Format` or `MakeBoxes` definition to hide unimportant informations from display:

```
MakeBoxes[SVDAnalysis[info_Association], form_] :=
  With[{n = ToBoxes[Length[info["SVDDecomposition"][[2]]], form]},
    RowBox[{"SVDAnalysis", "[<", n, ">]}]
  ]
```

The very useful part comes with `SubValues` of the chosen head. For example

```
SVDAnalysis[info_Association]["SingularValues"] := info["SVDDecomposition"][[2]]
(lca:SVDAnalysis[info_Association])["ConditionNumber"] := 
  With[{sigma = lca@"SingularValues"}, sigma[[1]] / sigma[[-1]]]
```

Maybe this approach is missing some foundamental point, but on a local kernel works more or less decently.

Because my laptop is slow and noisy under load and because in these days I have access to another faster desktop PC on the network, I tried to use a remote Kernel directly connected to the frontend running on my laptop.

I computed the slow SVD analysis of a large Matrix, says 4000x4000:

```
stiffness =  {{...}, ..., {...}};
load = {...};
svda = SVDAnalysis[stiffness, load];
```

which required some time but ended (please note `svda` has about an 800 MB `ByteCount`). At that point I tried

```
svda["ConditionNumber"]
```

but this fast 2-numbers division apparently never ends. Again, on a local kernel works.

I suppose the use of remote kernel raised a problem related to a wrong/inefficient design: probably, for some reason a huge amount of data is traveling on the network. But I don't understand why and how to properly refactor my approach.

- Maybe it's mandatory to use differents heads to build the preliminary
  computations and to wrap the association like
  `Interpolation`/`InterpolatingFunction` (I don't like to duplicate
  the symbols related to this operation in this and similar situation
  but...)?
- Maybe we need to `HoldAll` the symbol used to wrap preliminary
  results (but `InterpolatingFunction` doesn't)?
- Maybe it's mandatory to store preliminary results in a different way
  (e.g. in `OwnValue` or `DownValues` of a `Unique` symbol generated
  during construction) (but, again, `InterpolatingFunction` doesn't)?
- Maybe it's related with the MakeBoxes part?

Any helps to solve this issue and to better design this common construct is appreciated.